Modern ways to implement assignment for value types
This question is about how to implement assignment in modern C++ value types, with the goal of avoiding misleading code or code that is inconsistent with built-in behavior.
In C++, generated values (rvalue?) of built-in types are not assignable:
int generator_double() {
    return 50;
}
...
   generator_double() = 60;  // error: expression is not assignable

This is probably a good thing, because it doesn't give the illusion that something can be done with the returned value.
However, naively designed user classes do not follow this rule.
struct UserClass {
    int val_;
};

UserClass generator_user_class() {
    return UserClass{99};
}

...
    generator_user_class() = UserClass{66};  // compiles

This works and compiles, which can be misleading.
I guess this is allowed because operator= could have side effect that are not going to be discarded.
Or perhaps someone would like to pass this assigned value to a third function fun(generator_user_class1() = UserClass{66});, although for a pure value, this should be the same as fun(UserClass{66});.
So this inspires at least 3 or 4 different ways to implement assignments and incrementally improve on the possibly inconsistent initial version:

This is the default behavior:

 struct UserClass1 {
    int val_;

    UserClass1& operator=(UserClass1 const& other) & = default;
    UserClass1& operator=(UserClass1 const& other) && = default;
};

UserClass1 generator_user_class1() { return UserClass1{99}; }

...
    generator_user_class1() = UserClass1{66};  // compiles, can be misleading


disable assignments on r-values

struct UserClass2 {
    int val_;

    UserClass2& operator=(UserClass2 const& other) & = default;
    UserClass2&& operator=(UserClass2 const& other) && = delete;
};

UserClass2 generator_user_class2() { return UserClass2{99}; }
...
    generator_user_class2() = UserClass2{66};


allow assignments on r-value, as 1), but mark the return as no discard.

struct UserClass3 {
    int val_;

    UserClass3& operator=(UserClass3 const& other) & = default;
    [[nodiscard]] UserClass3&& operator=(UserClass3 const& other) && {
        return std::move(operator=(other));
    }
};

UserClass3 generator_user_class3() { return UserClass3{99}; }
...
    generator_user_class3() = UserClass3{66};  // warns because of [[nodiscard]]


a fourth option that would have been nice to make it work, is to declare the whole class as [[nodiscard]] and make all this work automatically, but it didn't help, it just forced me to implement operator= && to return by value.

Here all the options in Godbolt to play. https://godbolt.org/z/h68hrxY19
So, What the correct modern way to implement assignment?
Are there other idioms currently to handle this?
(For simplicity, the discussion can be restricted to types that are semantically values.)

EDIT 1:
I am told that option 2 is, in part, problematic because deleting some assignment operators is a bad idea and that this one is particular is deleted automatically because the line it has before.
In this scenario, I am going to amend option 2.
2 bis.
struct UserClass2bis {
    int val_;

    UserClass2bis& operator=(UserClass2bis const& other) & = default;
    // line removed: UserClass2bis&& operator=(UserClass2bis const& other) && = delete;
};

UserClass2bis generator_user_class2bis() { return UserClass2bis{99}; }
...
    generator_user_class2bis() = UserClass2bis{66};


https://godbolt.org/z/9YbPb1rqo
EDIT 2
Both answers suggest ignoring this problem.
One of the answers suggested that, if I do this at all, it would be preferable to do this:

Delete const& to take care of all the non-& cases, && and const&&.

struct UserClass2bisbis {
    int val_;

    UserClass2bisbis& operator=(UserClass2bisbis const& other) & = default;
    UserClass2bisbis&& operator=(UserClass2bisbis const& other) const& = delete;
};

UserClass2bisbis generator_user_class2bisbis() { return UserClass2bisbis{99}; }
...
    generator_user_class2bisbis() = UserClass2bisbis{66};

https://godbolt.org/z/jMze5nqqK

Possibly useful resource: C++ Core Guidelines

@Chris, thanks. I found this: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-assignment-op . It precisely talks about assignment on expressions (comment about const T&). There is no discussion on r-values, but it goes to say "do as the ints do", which is a motivation for this question.

Related: Assigning Rvalue returned from function to another Rvalue (asks why the "misleading code" is allowed in the first place)

related: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2019/01/03/const-is-a-contract/

related: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2024/12/13/wassign-to-class-rvalue/


What the correct modern way to implement assignment?

Most modern guidelines agree that the correct way is to ignore the problem of assigning to an rvalue. Core Guidelines say:

C.20: If you can avoid defining default operations, do <...> Note This
is known as “the rule of zero”.

Cppreference says:

Rule of zero
Classes that have custom destructors, copy/move
constructors or copy/move assignment operators should deal exclusively
with ownership (which follows from the Single Responsibility
Principle). Other classes should not have custom destructors,
copy/move constructors or copy/move assignment operators. [emphasis is mine]

But let's say you still want to catch "assignment to rvalue" bug. Let's consider your example, but start with std::vector<int> val_; member instead of int val;. I.e., start with:
struct UserClass {
    std::vector<int> val_;
};

Then, your 1st way of fixing the problem loses move semantics:
 struct UserClass2 {
    std::vector<int> val_;

    UserClass2& operator=(UserClass2 const& other) & = default;
    UserClass2& operator=(UserClass2 const& other) && = delete;
};

The problem is that by defining copy-assignment operator, you suppressed move constructor and move assignment. You have to add them:
 struct UserClass2 {
    std::vector<int> val_;

    UserClass2& operator=(UserClass2 const& other) & = default;
    UserClass2& operator=(UserClass2&& other) & = default;
    UserClass2(UserClass2&& other) = default;
}; 

Note that you do not need to delete any assignment operators: they are not generated because you have other assignment operators. I would probably follow  "the rule of 5" and add 2 other operators even though they are not strictly needed:
 struct UserClass2 {
    std::vector<int> val_;

    UserClass2& operator=(UserClass2 const& other) & = default;
    UserClass2& operator=(UserClass2&& other) & = default;
    UserClass2(UserClass2& other) = default;
    UserClass2(UserClass2&& other) = default;
    ~UserClass2() = default;
}; 

Now, what about your UserClass3 example? You could add 2 more [[nodiscard]] operators for copy assignment and move assignment, but, in my opinion, adding so much code just to mark something as "no discard" is not worth it.

Sure, I didn't want to distract the question with the move-assignments that could be accidentally disables. Thanks for bringing up that extra inconvenience. Another thing to take into account is that sufficiently complex classes could end up defining all four assignment operators for other reasons.

In general I agree with Eugene: the most popular idiom is to just do what the Rule of Zero would have given you. No ref-qualifier, return a reference to *this, done.

I think your choice of which two signatures to overload was unidiomatic. Generally, you don't want an overload set consisting of & and &&; you want & and const&. The latter way, the const& overload will pick up all three of &&, const&, and const&&. The former way, you'll have a "hole" in your overload set for const& and const&&, meaning that assigning to a const prvalue will fail in a subtly different way from assigning to a non-const prvalue (Godbolt).
In general, we expect to overload on && versus const& (move from mutable rvalues vs. copy everything else); rarely and bad-idea'ly overload on const&& versus const& (forbid prvalues versus support everything else); in your case overload on & versus const& (support mutable lvalues vs. forbid everything else). That is, "const& means 'everything else.'"

But I strongly recommend against your #2 (=delete), anyway. It is almost always a bad idea to =delete any constructor, because that messes with overload resolution (Godbolt):
struct RefToMutableInt {
  RefToMutableInt(int&);
  RefToMutableInt(const int&) = delete;  // This is a bad idea...
};
void f(RefToMutableInt);  // #1
void f(std::optional<int>);  // #2
f(42);  // should unambiguously call #2;
        // but is actually ambiguous because
        // deleted overloads still participate
        // in overload resolution

Now, an assignment operator isn't a constructor, and I'm not immediately able to think of an analogous example; but in general, we would much rather have a function not participate at all, than have it participate but then be deleted. (This is also going to be nicer from the compiler's point of view: fewer entities, faster overload resolution.)
And you don't need to =delete the assignment-to-rvalue: it won't exist anyway. (Godbolt.) Interestingly, there's a difference if you compile with gcc -fpermissive, since GCC still supports discarding const with a warning in -fpermissive mode. But I hope nobody is still using -fpermissive in the 2020s! And even if they are, I wouldn't bother writing even this one extra line of code to cater to them. -fpermissive users have made their bed; let them sleep in it.
struct A {
  A& operator=(const A&) &;
};

error: passing 'A' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
   12 |     prvalue() = a;
      |                 ^
// but this error is downgraded to a mere warning by -fpermissive


You didn't ask, but: If there's one thing about the assignment operator's signature that I often (>20% of the time) fiddle with, it's nothing to do with ref-qualification — it's the useless return type! I often just write
void operator=(const A& rhs) { ~~~~ }

This is a tiny microefficiency gain, avoids the potential for UB by forgetting to write return *this on all control paths, and also 100% forestalls the awful practice of client code's using the return value of assignment (e.g. a=b=c, e.g. if (a=b), but not if (auto a=b)). This makes type A fail to satisfy std::assignable_from and thus fail to satisfy std::regular; but that matters only if you're using Ranges stuff, which I'm not, so (A) I can afford to take this stand, and (B) if enough code stops exposing a return value from assignment then maybe in a decade from now the Ranges library will actually stop depending on it. (Also unfortunately, an operator= returning void cannot (yet) be =default'ed.)

What exactly is your criticism about #2? That I deleted one assignment? If so, this would have happened automatically anyway, as you say latter. Unfortunately, I didn't realize this when I asked the question, or perhaps I wanted to be explicit, confusing the point. I also realized that this is what Peter Sommerlad has been proposing and that I hadn't made the connection before. https://godbolt.org/z/KsYeEorr4

"this [deletion] would have happened anyway" — Nope! What would have happened anyway is that the operator= wouldn't have existed at all. That's different from being deleted. Compare the messages here: https://godbolt.org/z/b3PGzsKP9 — Now, is this subtle difference critical? I suspect it is not. But I'd still prefer to avoid the inconsistency (and save one line of code too). Or, as my next subsection says, at the very least you deleted the wrong signature for operator=.

I must have misinterpreted when you said, "And you don't need to =delete the assignment-to-rvalue: it won't exist anyway." But yes, "deleted" or "unresolved" were equally good to me.

Yes, I agree that ... const& = delete; is more general and gives a more explicit error message: https://godbolt.org/z/jMze5nqqK. See my second edit.
